# COM Class Factory Error

Tags: c#-4.0

I tried in console application it is showing Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: `80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`

This is the error. How to solve this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.Append("SELECT deptId ");
        query.Append(",[deptabbr], [deptname ], [deptnameLocal] ");
        query.Append(",[deptabbrLocal ]");
        //    , [UnitPrice], [UnitsInStock] ");
        //query.Append(",[UnitsOnOrder], [ReorderLevel], [Discontinued] ");
        query.Append("FROM [dbo].[mDepartment] ");
        //query.Append("JOIN Categories ON Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID ");
        //query.Append("ORDER BY Categories.CategoryName ");

        SQL.DataTable dtProducts = new SQL.DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=ADMIN-PC;uid=sa;pwd=microsoftsql;database=HPMS_IntranetApp;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query.ToString(), cn))
            {
                da.Fill(dtProducts); 
            }
        }

        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

        oXL = new Excel.Application();
       oXL.Visible = true;

        oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
        oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

        try
        {
            SQL.DataTable dtCategories = dtProducts.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "deptId");

            foreach (SQL.DataRow category in dtCategories.Rows)
            {
                oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oXL.Worksheets.Add();
                oSheet.Name = category[0].ToString().Replace(" ", "").Replace("  ", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("\\", "").Replace("*", "");

                string[] colNames = new string[dtProducts.Columns.Count];

                int col = 0;

                foreach (SQL.DataColumn dc in dtProducts.Columns)
                    colNames[col++] = dc.ColumnName;

                char lastColumn = (char)(65 + dtProducts.Columns.Count - 1);

                oSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Value2 = colNames;
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Font.Bold = true;
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

                SQL.DataRow[] dr = dtProducts.Select(string.Format("deptId='{0}'", category[0].ToString()));

                string[,] rowData = new string[dr.Count<SQL.DataRow>(), dtProducts.Columns.Count];

                int rowCnt = 0;
                int redRows = 2;
                foreach (SQL.DataRow row in dr)
                {                         
                    for (col = 0; col < dtProducts.Columns.Count; col++)
                    {
                        rowData[rowCnt, col] = row[col].ToString();
                    }

                    if (int.Parse(row["deptname"].ToString()) < int.Parse(row["deptnameLocal"].ToString()))
                    {
                        Range range = oSheet.get_Range("A" + redRows.ToString(), "J" + redRows.ToString());
                        range.Cells.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red; 
                    }
                    redRows++;
                    rowCnt++;
                }
                oSheet.get_Range("A2", lastColumn + rowCnt.ToString()).Value2 = rowData;
            }   

            oXL.Visible = true;
            oXL.UserControl = true;

            oWB.SaveAs("Products.xlsx",
                AccessMode: Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);  
        }
        finally
        {   
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must register COM component with this CLSID.

Comment: Your machine is seriously broken, registry corruption like this is rarely an isolated problem.  This ought to be noticeable in other places than just your program, the standard marshaller with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is used by a *lot* of software.  Feel free to panic.